# Eureka is unable to find port when running spring boot on a random port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grpc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Following are the dependencies in my local:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
grpc.server.port=${PORT:0}
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8791/eureka/
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=grpc-service
```

Eureka server is detecting port 8080 instead of the actual port used in the Eureka client. There are similar issues reported in the past, and it was fixed as per their developers. Did I miss anything on the above mentioned config?

**Update**

I modified my `application.properties` file with the below:

```
grpc.server.port=${PORT:0}
server.port=${grpc.server.port}
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8791/eureka/
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${server.port}
```

But now Eureka is not detecting the service at all.

Comment: Eureka assumes server.port is set. Since you are not, you will need to set eureka.instance.non-secure-port (or eureka.instance.secure-port is using https)

Comment: added `eureka.instance.non-secure-port=80` in `application.properties`, but still the same issue.

Comment: @spencergibb
I also tried `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort` , but no luck as well. Also, how can I set it to the actual random port generated for the service?

Comment: @spencergibb
Lastly, I tried `eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${server.port}` & `eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${grpc.server.port}`, but none of them fixed the issue. See my updated post above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making the below changes:

**application.xml**

```
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false
server.port=${grpc.server.port}
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8791/eureka/
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port=${grpc.server.port}
```

`grpc.server.port` is passed as `runtime` argument. After making these changes, `Eureka` is now detecting the exact port used in Eureka clients.